# mysql count having distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi im looking to get how many users that use one app use that app

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║    username  clientname     date         time          publishedapp    ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║    akirk   hplaptop1   30/07/2015   8:42:30.04    PB Desktop service   ║
║     john     dellPC1   27/07/2015   9:41:30.04    desktop@Work2-1      ║
║     john     dellPC1   27/07/2015   9:41:30.04    Word 2013            ║
║     karl delllaptop2   27/07/2015   9:40:21.00    Chrome               ║
║     karl delllaptop2   27/07/2015   9:40:21.00    Desktop with acrobat ║
║     jdoe       HPPC1   27/07/2015   9:40:15.00    Powerplan            ║
║     mrt        P2000   31/02/2015   10:03.20      PB Desktop service   ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I would be specting something like this:

```
PB DEsktop service: 2
Powerplan: 1
```

I've managed to get

```
PB DEsktop service: 2
desktop@Work2-1: 1
Desktop with acrobat: 1
Chrome: 1
Word 2013: 1
Powerplan: 1
```

with this query:

```
SELECT publishedapp, COUNT(DISTINCT username) as cnt
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY publishedapp
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: so, what's your que??

Comment: how many users that use a single app use that app? look at what im specting... I dont know how to query this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method that doesn't require a join:

```
select publishedapp, count(*) as NumberOfUsers
from (select username, min(publishedapp) as publishedapp
      from table t
      group by username
      having count(*) = 1
     ) u
group by publishedapp
order by count(*) desc;
```

If a user only has one app, then the minimum will be that app.

If a user could have an app multiple times (and you still want them), then change the `count(*)` in the subquery to `count(distinct publishedapp)`.

Comment: andby subquery you mean the HAVING bit?

Comment: @maco1717 . . . The query returns the number of users using the app.  The subquery is in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Im using PHP so I need a variable to read the "number of users" what would be the "variable name" on my query I can identify it as I can name it with AS would it be the u at the end of the from clause?

Comment: @maco1717 . . . Just give the column whatever name you want it to have.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT publishedapp, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM 
(
select username from tbl_name 
group by username
having count(*)=1
) as t1 inner join tbl_name as t2
on t1.username=t2.username
GROUP BY publishedapp
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: this is returning interesting values, but not consistent with my data... :S id like to know if there is a way to get the usernama back to contrast and see what is what im getting from here exactly, thanks.

Comment: You can add username in the first select as well as in the last group by clause

Comment: dont understand, here is what i tried `SELECT publishedapp, username, COUNT(*) as cnt,
FROM
(
select username from tbl_name
group by username
having count(*)<=1
) as t1 inner join tbl_name as t2
on t1.username=t2.username
GROUP BY publishedapp, username
ORDER BY cnt DESC`

Comment: Yes that will list out all users

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.publishedapp, COUNT (DISTINCT t.username)
FROM tbl_name t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT * 
               FROM tbl_name 
               WHERE publishedapp = t.publishedapp and 
                     username = t.username AND
                     datetime != t.datetime) -- or use ID if you have it
GROUP BY publishedapp
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: this is not working for me, what is datetime? i suppose both field concatenated... wouln't I have to concat them?

Comment: yes, it is combination of two fields, ideally you would have ID field in your table that you can use for comparison.